# Swift set variable in custom UIView Class

Tags: swift

I have set up a custom view from a xib (profileView). When a cell is selected in my 'chatPage' class I am attempting to set the token variable inside the profile class and print it when the view loads.

The code below doesn't output the token, its empty and I cannot get it to work.

How would I go about achieving this?

chatPage.swift

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       // Pass the user token to the profileView class.
        profileView().token = filteredArray[indexPath.row].token
         view.addSubview(profileView.create(height: view.frame.height, width: view.frame.width, x: view.frame.origin.x, y: view.frame.origin.y, tag: 104))
    }
```

custom profileView Class:

```
class profileView: UIView, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var token: String?

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!

    static func create(height: CGFloat,width:CGFloat,x:CGFloat,y:CGFloat,tag: Int) -> UIView{
        profileView().token = "1"
        let key = UINib(nibName: "profileView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        key.frame.size.height = height
        key.frame.size.width = width
        key.frame.origin.x = x
        key.frame.origin.y = y
        key.tag = tag
        return key
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        //custom logic goes here
    }
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if(scrollView.contentOffset.y < -60){
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
               self.frame.origin.y += self.frame.height
            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
                self.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the order of what you're doing. You are saying

```
profileView().token = filteredArray[indexPath.row].token
```

But then in the next line you say

```
profileView.create
```

And what does *it* do?

```
profileView().token = "1"
```

First you instantiate a profileView and set its token. Then you throw it away. Then you instantiate *another* profileView and set *its* token (to 1). Your first code is thus totally useless too.

Moreover, `profileView.create` also throws away *its* profileView. Your *second* code is thus totally useless.Thats two views you’ve created and thrown away so far.

Finally, you create a *third* view by loading it from a nib. That's the only one you actually do anything with. But it is just a UIView, not a profileView, and even if it were a profileView you *never* set its token.